# AWS EC2 can't access my ec2 public domain, tried many web solutions none worked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-security-group

I don't this is a very common question, I'm only asking it because I've already started some ec2 instances using the method I'll explain bellow and I succed, maybe EC2 changed something the right away to connect it by HTTP using public dns. Here are the steps I've always done and I don't know why it isn't working anymore.

public dns: [ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com](https://ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com)

1 - Settup the default security group, that is oppened for every traffic

[image: security group]

2 - Add IAM policity to this ec2, as you can see IAM function bellow

[image]

3 - Access SSH and configure nginx, I used putty and could enter on the instance. The configuration for nginx is `/etc/nginx/sites-avaiable/default`

```
## default nginx config

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;

  # front-end
  location / {
    root /var/www/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # node api
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
}
```

4 - Clone both my front-end and back-end repositories from github

5 - build production and move to /var/www/html all frontend dist files

[image]

6 - Start my node.js server using pm2

[image]

7 - Start nginx

`sudo nginx -t`

`sudo systemctl start nginx`

`sudo netstat -plant | grep 80`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21159/nginx: master
```

As you can see the port:80 is being listening by nginx

Guys I have no ideia why I can't access the public dns of this instance, I made everything identical as I've done in the past, It has always been working doing these steps, anything has changed using AWS EC2 ubuntu 20 instance, let me know. Thanks a lot, I'm headaching trying to figure this out.

Last steps to try to solve it is check nginx logs

`cd /var/log/nginx`

`2022/04/05 09:42:02 [error] 8216#8216: *1 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 103.178.236.40, server: _, request: "GET http://example.>`

But even doing this, it has not solved the issue:

`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html`

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the site via `https (443)` while it's running on `http (80)`.
Here is the result of curl.

```
root@MSI:~# curl -vk https://ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
*   Trying 23.22.52.143...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 23.22.52.143 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 443: Connection refused
root@MSI:~# curl -vk http://ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com
* Rebuilt URL to: http://ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
*   Trying 23.22.52.143...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com (23.22.52.143) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Tue, 05 Apr 2022 13:02:08 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 1676
< Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Apr 2022 09:54:30 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "624c11d6-68c"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
* Connection #0 to host ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com left intact
<!DOCTYPE html><html class="bg-image" lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link rel="my icon" href="/assets/icone.ico" type="image/x-icon"><title>Lab301mktdigital</title><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles/general.css"><link href="/css/app.9ba0b389.css" rel="preload" as="style"><link href="/css/chunk-vendors.f754c4c0.css" rel="preload" as="style"><link href="/js/app.5380592f.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/js/chunk-vendors.1ab5dd1a.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/css/chunk-vendors.f754c4c0.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="/css/app.9ba0b389.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but freelancer-front-end doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript><div id="app"></div><script src="/js/chunk-vendors.1ab5dd1a.js"></script><script src="/js/app.5380592f.js"></script></body></html>
```

From browser :
[image: site]

Comment: omg I tried everything to do it Correctly it was the url OMG